# find the directory using pattern and delete the content, not the directory itself

Tags: bash, find

I could traverse the directory sizes using pattern in find command:

```
find . -name "results_*" -exec du -sm '{}' \;
```

Now I would like to delete the content of those directories, but still retaining those directories themselves (the results_*) to create a placeholder that they existed and could be found in a backup.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match against the path instead:

```
find . -path "*/results_*/*" -delete
```

or, if your `find` doesn’t support `-delete`,

```
find . -path "*/results_*/*" -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune
```

This finds anything with `results_*` in its path, excluding the last path component; so all the contents of directories match `results_*` will be deleted, but the directories themselves will be left alone (unless they are themselves inside a directory matching `results_*`).